# Correlated SQL Server Subquery taking very long

Tags: query-optimization, correlated-subquery, database-indexes

> 1. I have this table: G_HIST with 700K rows and about 200 columns. Below is the
>    correlated query that is taking almost 6 minutes. Is there a better way to write it so
>    that it can take less  than half minute.
>
>    2. If not, what indexes I need to have on this table? Currently it has only PK Unique
>       index on Primary Keys made up of 10 columns.
>    3. Here is the code below to select current version of cycle filtering
>       participant_identifier:

```
select distinct Curr.Cycle_Number, Curr.Process_Date,Curr.Group_Policy_Number,
                                Curr.Record_Type, Curr.Participant_Identifier,Curr.Person_Type,
                                Curr.Effective_Date
                                FROM G_HIST as Curr 
                               
        WHERE Curr.Participant_Identifier not in (
                                   select prev.Participant_Identifier 
                                   from G_HIST as Prev
                                   where Prev.Cycle_Number = (
                                         select max(b.Cycle_Number)-1
                                         FROM G_HIST as b
                                       WHERE b.Group_Policy_Number = Curr. Group_Policy_Number
                                          )
                                          )
                    

                                 AND    Curr.[Cycle_Number] = (
                                 select max(a.[Cycle_Number])
                                 FROM G_HIST as a
                                 WHERE a.[Group_Policy_Number] = Curr.[Group_Policy_Number]
                                                               )
```

Comment: If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create. Use it, add the index, and repeat those two steps until things work better.

Answer (score 0):

You have aggregating -- MAX() -- correlated (dependent) subqueries. Those can be slow because they need to be re-evaluated for each row in the main query. Let's refactor them to ordinary subqueries. The ordinary subqueries need only be evaluated once.

You need a virtual table containing the largest `Cycle_Number` for each `Group_Policy_Number`. You get that with the following subquery.

```sql
    SELECT MAX(Cycle_Number) Max_Cycle_Number,
           Group_Policy_Number
      FROM GHIST
     GROUP BY Group_Policy_Number
```

This subquery will benefit, dramatically, from a multicolumn index on `(Group_Policy_Number, Max_Cycle_Number)`.

And you have this pattern:

```sql
WHERE someColumn NOT IN (a correlated subquery)
```

That `NOT IN` can be refactored to use the `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` pattern (also known as the antijoin pattern) and an ordinary subquery. I guess your business rule says you start by finding the participant numbers in the previous cycle.

This query, using a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), should get you that list of participant numbers from the previous cycle for each `Group_Policy_Number`. You might want to inspect some results from this to ensure it gives you what you want.

```sql
WITH 
Maxc AS (
    SELECT MAX(Cycle_Number) Max_Cycle_Number,
           Group_Policy_Number
      FROM GHIST
     GROUP BY Group_Policy_Number
),
PrevParticipant AS (
    SELECT Participant_Identifier,
           Group_Policy_Number
      FROM GHIST
      JOIN Maxc ON GHIST.Group_Policy_Number = Maxc.Group_Policy_Number
     WHERE GHIST.Cycle_Number = Maxc.Cycle_Number - 1
)
SELECT * FROM PrevParticipant;
```

Then we can use the `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` pattern.

So here is the refactored query,  **not debugged, use at your own risk.**

```sql
WITH 
Maxc AS (
    SELECT MAX(Cycle_Number) Max_Cycle_Number,
           Group_Policy_Number
      FROM G_HIST
     GROUP BY Group_Policy_Number
),
PrevParticipant AS (
    SELECT Participant_Identifier,
           Group_Policy_Number
      FROM G_HIST
      JOIN Maxc ON G_HIST.Group_Policy_Number = Maxc.Group_Policy_Number
     WHERE GHIST.Cycle_Number = Maxc.Cycle_Number - 1
)
SELECT DISTINCT Curr.whatever
  FROM G_HIST Curr
  JOIN Maxc 
          ON Curr.Group_Policy_Number = Maxc.Group_Policy_Number
  LEFT JOIN PrevParticipant
          ON Curr.Group_Policy_Number = PrevParticipant.Group_Policy_Number
         AND Curr.Participant_Number <> PrevParticiant.Participant_Number
 WHERE PrevParticipant.Group_Policy_Number IS NULL
   AND Curr.Cycle_Number = Maxc.Cycle_Number;
```

If you have SQL Server 2016 or earlier you won't be able to use Common Table Expressions. Let me know in a comment and I'll show you how to write the query without them.

You can use SSMS's Actual Execution Plan to identify any other indexes you need to speed up the whole query.

Comment: This is great! Thank you. My original query that I posted with correlated subqueries result in ~29K records. Your query results in ~30K records. Logically your query makes perfect sense. Not sure, why the count of records are different. BTW, the query execution time decreased to half as what was previous.